# Laravel - Controller works in Localhost and doesn't work in Production

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel controller like this-

```
public function detailedMapItem()
{
    $requestData = Request::all();
    //Update View Count - Not Working
    /*UserAdvertisementView::firstOrCreate([
                                    'user_id'   =>  Auth::user()->id,
                                    'add_id'    =>  $requestData['product_id']
                                ])->increment('total_view');*/
    //So do it with Query Bilder
    $user_id = 1;   //Default User ID for non logged in users
    if(Auth::check())
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $prev_element = DB::table('user_add_views')
                ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->where('add_id', $requestData['product_id']);
    if($prev_element->count()>0)
    {
        $prev_element=$prev_element->pluck('total_view');
        DB::table('user_add_views')
                ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->where('add_id', $requestData['product_id'])
                ->update([
                            'total_view' => $prev_element[0]+1
                        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        DB::table('user_add_views')->insert([
                                        'user_id'   =>  $user_id,
                                        'add_id'    =>  $requestData['product_id']
                                    ]);
    }
    //Return the Product detail
    $advertisement = Advertisement::with('AdvertisementImages')
                        ->find($requestData['product_id']);

    $add_owner  =   DB::table('users')
                        ->join('user_reviews', 'users.id', '=', 'user_reviews.add_owner_id')
                        ->select(
                                'users.id as user_id',
                                DB::raw("
                                            CASE WHEN users.profile_picture IS NULL or users.profile_picture = ''
                                                THEN
                                                    '".url('images/empty-profile.jpg')."'
                                                ELSE
                                                    CONCAT('".url('uploads')."','/', users.profile_picture)
                                                END
                                            as profile_picture"
                                        ),
                                DB::raw("CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS user_name"),
                                'users.cell_no as cell_no',
                                'users.website as website',
                                'users.email as email',
                                DB::raw("FLOOR( AVG(user_reviews.rating) ) AS user_rating")
                            )
                        ->where('id', $advertisement->user_id)
                        ->first();

    $reviews = DB::table('user_reviews')
                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_reviews.user_id')
                    ->select(
                                DB::raw("CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS user_name"),
                                'user_reviews.review as review',
                                'user_reviews.rating as rating',
                                DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(user_reviews.updated_at,'%D %b %Y, %r') AS added_on")
                            )
                    ->where('add_id', $requestData['product_id'])
                    ->orderBy('user_reviews.updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();

    return [
                'advertisement' =>  $advertisement,
                'reviews'       =>  $reviews,
                'add_owner'     =>  $add_owner
            ];
}
```

It is *working perfectly* in **localhost**.

But problem is, I am not getting perfect data from it in **production**.

`'advertisement'    =>  $advertisement` data is found in production.

But `'add_owner'        =>  $add_owner` is found as `NULL`.

I can assure that it is not problem of **MySQL DB**.

Can be there any reason behind that?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Is your dev box homestead and your production box is something else like a custom set up ?

Comment: Not homestead, it is basic OS, everything configured in Apache.


And production is shared hosting in Ubuntu in godaddy.com and server is apache

Comment: Are you completely sure that is not a MySQL problem? The MySQL instances have the same version? Both Localhost and Production servers use the same php-mysql extension? Both servers use the same MySQL driver?

Comment: do you have the direct access to mysql (phpmyadmin, workbenc, etc.)? run the same query there

Comment: Yes, because it is working perfectly in localhost and I have checked production DB with phpmyadmin

Comment: Maybe this one `->where('add_id', $requestData['product_id'])` has some issues?

Comment: No way, because I am getting data from `'advertisement'    =>  $advertisement` and in there, data is perfect

Comment: My first red flag, with the above information, is the `url()` functions within the `DB::raw()` section of the `$add_owner` query. Why don't you dump the contents of those instances of `url()` and make sure they match what you expect them to match (i.e. what's in the DB).

Comment: I got u, it  is also not a problem because I am generating custom response and url will act as a string